# MassTransit Kafka Consumer Console App fails to connect to Kafka Topic Endpoint repeatedly

Tags: c#, .net, apache-kafka, masstransit, testcontainers

I am trying to create a Kafka Consumer that consumes data from a topic, using MassTransit. As part of this, I am creating integration tests for it using Testcontainers, in particular a Kafka Testcontainer.

The problem I am facing is that the consumer fails to connect to the Kafka Container topic, and so it's not receiving any messages.

I've tried reconfiguring ports of the Kafka container with every configuration under the sun and nothing seems to be working

MassTransit setup:

```
builder.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                var topicName = configuration["Kafka:TopicName"];
                var consumerGroupName = configuration["Kafka:ConsumerGroupName"];

                services.AddLogging(c => c.AddConsole());
                services.AddSingleton(configuration);
                services.AddMediatR(cfg => cfg.RegisterServicesFromAssemblyContaining<Program>());

                services.AddMassTransit(x =>
                {
                    
                    x.UsingInMemory((context, config) => config.ConfigureEndpoints(context));
                    x.AddRider(rider =>
                    {
                        rider.AddConsumer<LocationsMessageConsumer>();
                        rider.UsingKafka((context, k) =>
                        {
                            k.Host(configuration["Kafka:Endpoint"]);
                            k.TopicEndpoint<Null, string>(topicName, consumerGroupName, e =>
                            {
                                e.ConfigureConsumer<LocationsMessageConsumer>(context);
                            });
                        });

                    });
                });
```

Basic Consumer:

```
public class KafkaMessageConsumer : IConsumer<string>
    {
        public virtual Task Consume(ConsumeContext<string> context)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

Kafka Container Setup:

```
public async Task<KafkaContainer> SetupKafkaContainer(INetwork network)
        {
            KafkaContainer kafkaContainer = new KafkaBuilder()
                .WithImage("confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest")
                .WithNetwork(network)
                .WithName(_kafkaContainerName)
                .WithPortBinding(_kafkaPort, 9092)
                .WithEnvironment("ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER", "yes")
                .WithEnvironment("KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS", $"PLAINTEXT://:9092")
                .WithEnvironment("KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS", $"PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092")
                .Build();

            await kafkaContainer.StartAsync();

            return kafkaContainer;
        }
```

Error seen in consumer container:

`warn: MassTransit[0] Consumer [] error (Local_Transport): localhost:9092/bootstrap: Connect to ipv4#127.0.0.1:9092 failed: Connection refused (after 0ms in state CONNECT) on locations warn: MassTransit[0] Consumer [] error (Local_AllBrokersDown): 1/1 brokers are down on locations`

I have tried using a non-MassTransit sender and receiver to confirm that messages can be sent through the topic without issue.

`[2023-09-22 14:49:19,695] DEBUG [PartitionStateMachine controllerId=1] Started partition state machine with initial state -> HashMap() (kafka.controller.ZkPartitionStateMachine) [2023-09-22 14:49:19,695] INFO [Controller id=1] Ready to serve as the new controller with epoch 1 (kafka.controller.KafkaController) [2023-09-22 14:49:19,695] WARN [RequestSendThread controllerId=1] Controller 1's connection to broker 172.31.0.2:9093 (id: 1 rack: null) was unsuccessful (kafka.controller.RequestSendThread) java.io.IOException: Connection to 172.31.0.2:9093 (id: 1 rack: null) failed. at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClientUtils.awaitReady(NetworkClientUtils.java:70) at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.brokerReady(ControllerChannelManager.scala:296) at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.doWork(ControllerChannelManager.scala:249) at org.apache.kafka.server.util.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.java:127) [2023-09-22 14:49:19,698] INFO [Controller id=1, targetBrokerId=1] Client requested connection close from node 1 (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)`

Answer (score 0):

Can you get container logs? I suspect it's not actually starting at all.

Confluent images don't use KAFKA_CFG prefix, only bitnami/kafka container does. Therefore, the configs you've set aren't accepted, causing the server to be misconfigured

You'll also need KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT, for example

Comment: The kafka container is throwing an error, I've put it in the main question. I believe the Kafka container has zookeeper built in

Comment: No, the container does not have Zookeeper built in. You must run that separately. Also, the logs say port 9093 is currently being used, which you've never configured, and thats not a default.

Comment: I've confirmed that the Kafka container runs properly and can receive and give out messages outside of MassTransit, so the problem seems to only come from the connection between MassTransit and Kafka

Comment: But it shouldn't be. Look at the logs... `Connection to 172.31.0.2:9093 (id: 1 rack: null) failed`... Receive messages how? What tool? What bootstrap address? Does that differ from the one you're using? We cannot see what your `configuration` variable is set to

Comment: And like I said, `KAFKA_CFG` variables don't setup that image correctly. If you were to exec into the container and look at the server.properties at the listeners settings, you'd see them starting with `cfg.`, which isn't valid

Answer (score 0):

Well, from the error you posted, it's trying to connect to `127.0.0.1` which is the default if you don't configure a host. It seems that your:

```cs
k.Host(configuration["Kafka:Endpoint"]);
```

Isn't returning what you expect, it should be of type `string[]` and contain the list of host names/ports where Kafka is reachable. Such as:

`new []{ "host-a:9092", "host-b:9092" }`

Comment: Testcontainers is running the broker on localhost